# Dropdown created dynamically not opening in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I have created a dynamic dropdown list using jquery. This dropdown will get bound to kendo grid column based on certain condition. Refer the below code

```
 CreateDropDown: function (e, grid, defaultvalue) {
 var field = $("#" + grid).data("kendoGrid").columns[e.index()].field;
 $("#" + field).hide();
 var kendoddl = $("<input id='DDL'  />");
 e.append(kendoddl);       
 $("#DDL").find('select').append( $("#DDL").kendoDropDownList({
     dataTextField: 'LevelName',
     dataValueField: 'Levelvalue',
     index: 0,
     change: LocalSetup.LevelOnSelect,
     dataSource: {
         transport: {
             read: {
                 url: "/ONT/TYK/GetDropDowndata"
             }
         },
         serverFiltering: true
     },
 })
);
var value = LocalSetup.checkLevelValue(defaultvalue);
var dropdownlist = $("#DDL").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.value(value);
},
```

The code works fine when viewed from IE. But the issue occurs in Chrome. The dropdown does not open and display the options. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you please check your console in Google chrome and let us know what error you see?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen No. I don't see any error.